# Table td content out of td after vertical rotation

Tags: html, css

I tried to fix this with `height` styling but it is not working. basically I am using `table-layout: fixed`.

[image]

CSS

```
.test-table.table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.test-table.table>tbody>tr>td {
  padding: 0;
  width: 10px;
}

.test-table.table>tbody>tr>td:first-child {
  width: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.test-table.table>tbody>tr:last-child>td {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <table class="table table-bordered test-table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>h</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>09:15 AM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your html code.

Comment: @vel I tried also with width but it's not working.

Comment: @selami Nothing special with html markup. Just general markup that's why didn't paste it.

Comment: can you pos html code?

Comment: Yea sure not an issue.

Comment: There is some php code that's why I didn't print all of that just print the base markup.

Comment: we need some more html script and your css. I cannot find any issue that you posted html

Comment: this is your script posted https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/50wLy7rr/. is there any issue?

Comment: I got a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just check [this](https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/)

```
<th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
```

You just try this look like

```
th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I just did few tweaks and it worked.